# Finite fibre implies locally finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a dominant map of irreducible $k$ varieties where $k$ is alg closed. Let $f^{-1}(fx)$ be a finite set for some $x \in X$.

> A lecture note I'm reading says that it implies $f$ is locally finite at $x$. How can one prove this?

At the level of affine varieties it means if we have a ring morphism $R \to S$ such that there exists a prime $p \subset S$ with finitely many primes $q_i$ lying over it, then even if $R \to S$ may not be an integral extension, at least some localisation will be integral extension.

This leads me to my next question -

> Can we have a ring morphism $R \to S$ such that there are finitely many primes over each prime, but $S$ is not an integral extension of $R$? Of course I'd want a non trivial examples instead of ones involving fields where there are no non trivial prime ideals to begin with!

Comment: For your second question, do you want all fibers to be nonempty or some extra condition? If you allow for empty fibers, don't simple localization examples work? For example, for a field $F$, take $F[X] \to F[X, X^{-1}]$.

Comment: As noted, the answer to the second question is Yes, but there is the following result (Zariski's main theorem). Let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$-algebra, quasi-finite over
$A$, and let $A^{\prime}$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $B$. Then the map $Spec B\rightarrow Spec A^{\prime}$ is an open immersion. See Section 17 of Milne's notes on Commutative Algebra